# Parse cloud code - modifying all PFUsers

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, pfuser

I'm trying to create a cloud Job that takes the users full name or username and saves it in lower case in another column. here's what I have so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('normaliseUsername',function(request, status) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.find({
        success: function(items){

            for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
                var user = items[i];
                console.log(user);
                var changed = user["nameChanged"];
                if (changed === true) {
                    var username = user.username;
                    user.set("lowerCaseName",username.toLowerCase());
                } else {
                    var realName = user["firstName"] + " " + user["lastName"];
                    user.set("lowerCaseName",realName.toLowerCase());
                }
                user.save();
            }

        }
    });
});
```

This results in a new column, `lowerCaseName`, full of `undefined`.

how do I access properties of a PFUser in this instance? I have tried using `user.get('');` but it says `Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way :

```
Parse.Cloud.job("normaliseUsername", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var count_user = 0;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.descending('updatedAt');  
    query.Exist('nameChanged'); 
    query.limit(1000);  
    return query.find().then(function(users) {
        return Parse.Promise.when(users.map(function(user) {
            count_user+= 1;
            if (user.get("nameChanged")) {
                user.set("canonical_firstname", user.get("username").toLowerCase());
            } else {
                var realName = user.get("firstname") + ' ' + user.get("lastname");
                user.set("lowerCaseName", realName.toLowerCase());                              
            }
            return user.save();
        }));
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("normaliseUsername with " + count_user + " user(s) updated.");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    });
});
```

Your loop with `for`, will never works, you need to use `Promise`. More information here : http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/

The way the above script works, you will work with Promise in `Parallel`, not in Series : https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises

Comment: You can either keep the return or remove it, you don't really need it, except if your code need later to use each users object. That won't affect performance on Parse's side.

Comment: great this worked! - i didn't need the `exists`  predicate, though (which I think you misspelled)