# Edit data using a function from parse cloud code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

Im trying to change 10 values from my parse database using a cloud code function.
I need to save the `name` in a new value called `nameLowerCase`.

This is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("nameToLowerCase", function(request, response) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Dog").limit(10);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i){

        var name = results[i].get("name").toLowerCase();

        results[i].save({
          nameLowerCase: name
        });

      }
      response.success("the end");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Im getting the response ok, but nothing changes on my DB.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You're only setting one value to lowercase

Comment: @cricket_007 why?

Comment: Youre setting only one new field. `nameLowerCase: name`, not updating the existing one

Comment: Sorry, my answer is bad explained, Im trying to save the name in a new var called nameLoweCase

Comment: Okay, and AFAIK, that's what the save function is doing...

Comment: No, my function isnt saving any value, nameLowerCase is empty

Comment: Then maybe `results[i].get("name")` is empty

Comment: No, all the names have a value, could be the promises? Im just lookig this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31116098/3994630

Comment: I mean, `save` would be not blocking, I don't think. Promises could help, sure, but the code you have looks okay to me (been awhile since using parse, though)

Comment: Maybe Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() or any similar?

Comment: What about it? If the master key was wrong, you wouldn't get a success response

Comment: Omg now im getting code":141,"error":"Invalid function using a simple hello world function

Comment: Sure.. If you didn't `Parse.Cloud.define("hello"` **and** deploy that new code to Parse Server

Comment: I have a new big problem, Im trying to edit my cloud code but this not works, the problem is that if a try with an old function it is working, but i deleted it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136631/discussion-between-pablo-cegarra-and-cricket-007).